# Compile time error even after adding maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Even after adding maven dependency in pom file, the **mvn clean package** gives below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
2:compile (default-compile) on project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/my-project/core/src/main/java/com/integration/test/core/Myjavaclass.java:[18,37] package does not exist
```

Comment: Maven is ok and you don't need to add dependency in `pom`, probably there is problem with your project structure.

Comment: It is strange that you don't have a package name in your error message. Does Myjavaclass.java have Syntax errors? What does Eclipse/IntelliJ say about it?

Answer (score 0):

check if this file is there in the path

D:/my-project/core/src/main/java/com/integration/test/core/Myjavaclass.java

Probably this file is missing so maven is not able to compile.

Comment: It is saying package does not exist, it means the file is there and it is not able to resolve the package.

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved now. There was problem with the version of dependency.